# Make a Query with a Pointer in Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a Query with a Pointer in Parse.

Basically I have two classes `"commentsTable"` and `"_User"`, I want to get the comment of the user from class `"commentsTable"` on a determined post, and then get the `username` and the `profile_pic` from the class `"_User"`

**_User Class**
[image]

**commentsTable Class**
[image]

```
    func loadAndShowComments(){
    let query2 = PFQuery(className: "commentsTable")
    query2.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query2.whereKey("newsColumns", equalTo: printteste!)
    query2.includeKey("username")

    query2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {

            for object in objects {

                print(object["commentColumn"])

            }

        }


        for cardset in objects! {
            var lesson = cardset["username"] as! PFObject
            var name = lesson["username"] as! String
            print("By user: \(name)")
        }
```

I'm able to see the query, I print the result an I have the following output:

```
This is a post!
This is a test post!
By user: teste@teste.com
By user: mmachado
```

And in my app I display this informations inside a TableView, I'm successfully can show the results for the Query in the func `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    if let usuarioComentario = object?["commentColumn"] as? String {
        cell?.usuarioComentario?.text = usuarioComentario
    }
```

But I'm no able to return the values of my other class, `_User`

I think I misunderstood some concept but at this point I don't know what concept, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `query2.includeKey("username")` you are already retrieving *all* of the `User` data associated with each `commentsTable` object.

You can access the related `User` data using the following.

```
if let commentUser = object["username"] as? PFUser {
    let name = commentUser["username"] as! String
    let profilePicture = commentUser["profile_pic"] as! PFFile
}
```

You need to store the query results to an array for later use if you aren't already. If you are using Parse's provided `PFQueryTableViewController` this will be handled for you by implementing the `queryForTable()` method and the results are automatically stored in an array of dictionaries called `objects`.

It is also worth noting that you will have to still have to load the `PFFile` because they are not included in query results. You will want to assign the `PFFile` to a `PFImageView` and then call `loadInBackground`. See the example below.

```
let imageView = PFImageView()

// Set placeholder image
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

// Set remote image
imageView.file = profilePicture

// Once the download completes, the remote image will be displayed
imageView.loadInBackground { (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")            
    } else {
        println("image loaded")
    }
}
```

Lastly, I'd recommend changing the name of the `User` pointer within `commentsTable` from "username" to "user" so there is no confusion with the username field of the user class. [Here's a link to a great tutorial which you may also find helpful](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581)

Comment: @Rusell   Perfect explanation, I've already knew about the how to load a PFFile and the website [medium.com](http://medium.com) ' my question really was about how to get the content from my other class, your explanation solved my doubts, also thanks for the recommendation to change the name of my user pointer, from `username` to `user`

Comment: I'll remove this comment very soon, but could you guys help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606788/swift-how-to-get-parses-many-users-name-and-photo   I think you know very well how to manage, but your answers are not applicable to my problem (at least, I don't understand how)