# Swift: how to get Parse's many user's name and photo

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have a bunch of users on my message app, fetching my "messages" class I need to get sender's first and last name and profile image from their Parse profile on my app in order to show them in each message on the tableView.

I just want to show in tableView the name of users in class "messages" contained in the column "sender" wich contains pointers to PFUsers (of which I need "first_name", "last_name", "profile_picture")

my users class

[image]

my message class

[image]

update!

can't get where is the problem, if I downCast something, something else must be changed. here the updated code:

```
findTimeLineDataQuery.includeKey("sender")


findTimeLineDataQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) in

    if let objects = objects where error == nil {

        var chats:(timelinechatsData: [String], chatsDate: [NSDate]) = ([], []) //date might be NSDate
        var message: (messageObjts: [String], messageSender: [String]) = ([], [])

        var datesToString: [String] {
            get {
                var stringDates:[String] = []
                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //change the format as you wish
                for date in dates {
                    stringDates.append(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
                }
                return stringDates
            }
        }

        for singleObject in objects {

            if let user = singleObject["sender"] as? PFObject {
                let first_name = user["first_name"] as! String
                let last_name = user["last_name"] as! String

                //Cast it to how you saved it. I can't see it from the picture so I assumed you saved it as NSData
                let picture = user["picture"] as! NSData
                self.picturesProfilesArray.append(picture)
                //once you fetch the user data, you can save it in a dictionary or however you want and later call it from cellForRowAtIndex
            }



            if let stringData = singleObject["message"] as? String {

                chats.timelinechatsData.append(stringData)

                if let messageDate = singleObject.createdAt {
                    chats.chatsDate.append(messageDate!)
                }
            }

            //new
            if let messageObject = singleObject["messageObject"] as? String {
                message.messageObjts.append(messageObject)
            }

            //new senderNickname
            if let messageSender = singleObject["senderNickname"] as? String {
                message.messageSender.append(messageSender)
            }
        }

        //update self
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.timelineChatsDataArray += chats.timelinechatsData
            self.chatsDateArray += datesToString
            self.messageObjectArray += message.messageObjts
            self.messageSenderArray += message.messageSender

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
```

changes

so my

```
var chatsDateArray : [NSDate] = []
```

and

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
        let useDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.chatsDateArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.dateMessageLabel.text = useDate
```

should become

```
    var chatsDateArray : [String] = []

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
        let useDate = String(self.chatsDateArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.dateMessageLabel.text = useDate
```

but this causes:

```
Initialization of immutable value 'first_name' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

Initialization of immutable value 'last_name' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
```

this disappears by changing var chat (chatsDate) back to string
, but this causes

```
 Cannot convert value of type 'NSDate' to expected argument type 'String'
```

on

```
if let messageDate = singleObject.createdAt {
                        chats.chatsDate.append(messageDate!)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'includeKey' to access pointer values of related classes

```
findTimeLineDataQuery.includeKey("sender")

findTimeLineDataQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) in

    if let objects = objects where error == nil {

        var chats:(timelinechatsData: [String], chatsDate: [NSDate]) = ([], []) //date might be NSDate
        var message: (messageObjts: [String], messageSender: [String]) = ([], [])

        var datesToString: [String] {
             get {
                 var stringDates:[String] = []
                 let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                 formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //change the format as you wish
                 for date in dates {
                     stringDates.append(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
                 }
                 return stringDates
             }
        }

        for singleObject in objects {

            if let user = singleObject["sender"] as! PFObject {
                let first_name = user["first_name"] as! String
                let last_name = user["last_name"] as! String

                //Cast it to how you saved it. I can't see it from the picture so I assumed you saved it as NSData
                let picture = user["picture"] as! NSData
                picturesProfilesArray.append(picture)
                //once you fetch the user data, you can save it in a dictionary or however you want and later call it from cellForRowAtIndex
            }



            if let stringData = singleObject["message"] as? String {

                chats.timelinechatsData.append(stringData)

                if let messageDate = singleObject.createdAt {
                    chats.chatsDate.append(messageDate)
                }
            }

            //new
            if let messageObject = singleObject["messageObject"] as? String {
                message.messageObjts.append(messageObject)
            }

            //new senderNickname
            if let messageSender = singleObject["senderNickname"] as? String {
                message.messageSender.append(messageSender)
            }
        }

        //update self
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.timelineChatsDataArray += chats.timelinechatsData
            self.chatsDateArray += datesToString
            self.messageObjectArray += message.messageObjts
            self.messageSenderArray += message.messageSender

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks again Lukas, take a look to the updated question, I changed a String to NSDate but got warnings

Comment: (maybe I didn't explained it well, but my intent was retrive name and image from the "sender" pointer, not senderNickname, does this change your solution?

Comment: depends on how your entity is set up. can you post more revealing picture

Comment: added more images and made clearer the question, hope this helps!

Comment: I guess I answered your question now

Comment: we are almost there! I updated code (changed "lesson" with "sender", right?) and changed some unwrap (images are going in `                        picturesProfilesArray.append(picture)
`), but still have those two warnings on arrays literals, tried many down casting, but still going mad!

Comment: well, those are pretty easy errors. updated the answer

Comment: getDatesAsString is used before its declaration, tried to put it in the asynch statement, before it's called, but says "/Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[NSDate]' and '[String]'" in relation to message and object array, could I use append(message.messageObjts) ??

Comment: I changed it to a computed property that returns string array of dates. This is a better approach I think

Comment: nope :( that warning remains, seems array cannot accept `+=`, more, in `datesToString` Xcode says that `dates` is an unresolvedidentifier , did you mean `for date in chats {` ???

Comment: It should work as long as both sides are same type arrays. make sure self.yourArray is same type the array on the other end of += and the operator should work

Comment: updated question with changes following your instructions, but still got this in datesToString Xcode says that dates is an unresolvedidentifier , did you mean for date in chats { ??? and your two constants regarding names are now unused (I think we are close to answer the question!)